# When is it appropriate to use a likelihood evaluation rather than least squares fitting?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, likelihood-ratio

I realise this might be a very open ended question, and there probably isn't a straight forward answer, but here goes:

I have been learning more about Likelihood evaluation (LLE, MLE,LRE) techniques. Especially in the context of extracting parameter estimates and errors on those parameters from distributions. I have also been playing with using a likelihood evaluation techniques as a means of fitting a theoretical curve/model to data.

I have found this is especially useful if I know the noise on the data is non-Gaussian, and I also know the details of the distribution it comes from.

So my question is when is it best to use a likelihood evaluation over more conventional fitting methods like least-squares?

Is it a case that likelihood evaluations are simply a more modern solution? Are they intrinsically better? Superficially a least-squares algorithm looks like a very specific form of likelihood evaluation which assumes Gaussian statistics.

Is there an argument to abandon least-square fitting methods altogether and exclusively use likelihood methods?

Answer (score 1):

Hi: If you have a linear model, then there is a closed form solution for the coefficients and these will be the same ones that would result if you assumed a normal distribution for the error term ( of the linear model ) and then maximized the resulting likelihood function.

In all other cases ( or atleast most that I know of ), non-linear models or non-gaussian errors or correlated errors of some kind, you'll need to maximize the likelihood because there is no closed form solution like least squares. A lot of these cases fall under the class of generalized linear models. In these cases, using least squares is not appropriate.

So, linear models with normally distributed errors is kind of a lucky case in the sense that doing least squares ( i.e: OLS ) is the same as maximizing the likelihood.

Maximizing likelihoods is often more complicated and more computationally intense and there can be numerical issues to deal with. That's why OLS is convenient.

Comment: So to paraphrase you a little, it would be fair to say: In most non-linear problem cases you would want to use a likelihood approach. However the trade-off is that this is computationally demanding, and that in a lot of cases while OLS is "worse" its not so much worse that it's worth the trade-off in computational demand. 

So it's up to you to decide whether your problem specifically requires likelihood methods, or if you can make do with OLS.

Comment: Hi: the decision is pretty easy actually. If It's an  OLS model, then use the closed form solution of OLS. Other than that case, I can't see where one would use closed form solution of OLS. The likelihood would always be preferred because it's not an approximation. It's exact.